# why hr behave's weirdly within a table?

Tags: html, css

I was creating my website and ran into a weird problem in table, that when i try to insert a hr under the  it places the hr above the division somehow.

I want a hr under every row so as to make every row seperate with a hr.

```html
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:48%; align-items:center;">
        <table style=" width:380px; height:100px; position: relative;margin: auto;">
            <th style="font-size:35px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;">Nutrition Facts</th>
            <th style="font-size:20px; text-align: right;">Per Serving 100ml</th>
            <tr style="border-bottom: 3px;">
                <td>Energy</td>
                <td style="float:right;">19.7 kcal</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carbohydrates</td>
                <td style="float:right;">5 g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sugar</td>
                <td style="float:right;">4.8 g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Protien</td>
                <td style="float:right;">0 g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fat</td>
                <td style="float:right;">0 g</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="width:53%;">
        <img style="height:450px; padding-top:50px; float:left;" src="https://www.diabete.qc.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Les-fruits-768x768.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Already tried placing hr in td, tr and table.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the `td` a bottom border. If the td's have no space between them, it will appear as a hr.

Note: instead of using `float:right` you should use `text-align:right`.

```
td {
  text-align:right;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
table {
  border:0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

UPDATE

As Alohci pointed out, `tr` can have a style if you set the border spacing!

```
tr {
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
table {
  border:0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[image]

Comment: why doesn't it work with tr ? since i want it under a row .

Comment: Apparently, `<tr>` has no `border` styling options. That's why I put it on the `td`. As long as the `td`'s have no space between them, it should look the same.

Comment: @LakshayKalra Tables have two border models: "separated" and "collapsing". You can have borders on tr elements only in the collapsing border model, which you select with `border-collapse: collapse`. The default is the separated border model.